# Gradle: dependency on tag in other repository

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

Is there a way to specify a tag in another repository as a dependency in Gradle?

I have a project x in repository a that depends on the tag tags/foo-1.2 in repository b. Is it possible to cause Gradle to checkout this dependency as a source dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not something that's currently supported out-of-the-box. Depending on your exact needs, you could:

- check out the other project (using a third-party SCM plugin or an `Exec` task), build it separately (using a `GradleBuild` task), and do something with its outputs (e.g. put them on the former build's compile class path).
- use Prezi's [Pride](https://github.com/prezi/pride) tool to dynamically create a multi-project build spanning multiple SCM repositories.
- use SVN externals/Git submodules/etc. to create a unified filesystem view that allows to define a multi-project build.